# How to have two footnote counters running simultaneously?

Tags: footnotes

When preparing translations or critical editions, one naturally wants to distinguish footnotes that were present in the original from footnotes added by the current translator or editor. But information on how to have two separate footnote classes running simultaneously (one taking Arabic numbers and the other taking symbols or Roman letters) seems quite hard to find. As far as I can see, no resetting-based solution will work, because footnotes of the two classes may be interleaved on the same page. Can anyone help?

Comment: You might be interested in the `bigfoot` package.

Comment: manyfoot.sty also one of a better supporter for your requirement...

Comment: There are some packages for critical editions, have a look ad reledmac and reledpar. If you »legatrix« are providing more sophisticated legal documents, edit your question. In general, for LaTeX beginners, it is often better to ask what you really want to do and refrain from asking a kind of special question, like here about footnote counters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\makeatletter
\newfootnote{A}
\newfootnote{B}
\newcounter{footnoteA}
\newcommand{\footnoteA}{%
   \stepcounter{footnoteA}%
   \Footnotemark\thefootnoteA \FootnotetextA{}}
\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\footnoteB}{%
   \stepcounter{footnoteB}%
   \Footnotemark\thefootnoteB \FootnotetextB\thefootnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In this chapter I begin by considering in greater depth these
observations of science\footnoteA{First footnote} as a human project and of the complexity
of the world. In this chapter, I have argued that science is in
the business of discovering causal patterns in the\footnoteB{Second
type of footnote} face of causal
complexity, and that idealizations play a particularly valuable
role in enabling the representation of causal patterns. I have
suggested that there are many different reasons to idealize that,
in various combinations, motivate idealization. And I have argued
that idealizations themselves play a positive representational
role\index{idealization!representing as-if}, representing systems
as if they had features they do not.


\end{document}
```